# How do I solve this question based on induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

If $m, n, p, q$ are non-negative integers prove that

$$\sum^q_{m=0}(n-m)\frac{(p+m)!}{m!}=\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q}{p+2}\right)$$

Comment: Try induction over $q$. The base case $q=0$ is clear since $np!=(p+1)! \frac{n}{p+1}$

Comment: also what did you try to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induction step becomes proving that
$$
\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q}{p+2}\right)+
(n-q-1)\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(q+1)!}=
\frac{(p+q+2)!}{(q+1)!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q+1}{p+2}\right)
$$
In the left-hand side we can collect
$$
\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}
$$
so it becomes
$$
\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}
\left(
\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q}{p+2}+\frac{n-q-1}{q+1}
\right)\tag{*}
$$
Let's consider only the expression in parentheses:
$$
\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q}{p+2}+\frac{n-q-1}{q+1}=
\frac{n}{p+1}+\frac{n}{q+1}-\frac{q}{p+2}-1=
\frac{n(p+q+2)}{(p+1)(q+1)}-\frac{p+q+2}{p+2}
$$
Collect $p+q+2$ to get
$$
(p+q+2)\left(\frac{n}{(p+1)(q+1)}-\frac{q+1}{(p+2)(q+1)}\right)
$$
Now…

Answer (score 1):

Induction on $q$

Induction basis:

for $q=0$, LHS=n.p!=RHS, the equality holds.

Induction hypothesis: for $<=q$ let the equality hold.

Induction step: for $q+1$, let's prove the equality holds.

$\sum \limits _{n=0}^{q+1}(n-m)\frac{(p+m)!}{m!}$
$=\sum \limits _{n=0}^{q}(n-m)\frac{(p+m)!}{m!} + (n-m)\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(q+1)!}$
$=\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q}{p+2}\right) + (n-(q+1))\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(q+1)!}$                 (by induction hypothesis)
$=\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}\right)-\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{q}{p+2}\right) + (n-(q+1))\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(q+1)!}$
$=\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}\right) + n\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(q+1)!}-\frac{(p+q+1)!}{q!}\left(\frac{q}{p+2}\right) - (q+1)\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(q+1)!}$
$=\frac{(p+q+1)!n}{(p+1)(q+1)!}\left((q+1)+(p+1)\right) -\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(p+2)q!}\left(q+ (p+2)\right)$
$=\frac{(p+q+1)!n}{(p+1)(q+1)!}\left(p+q+2\right) -\frac{(p+q+1)!}{(p+2)q!}\left(p+q+2\right)$
$=\frac{(p+q+2)!n}{(p+1)(q+1)!}-\frac{(p+q+2)!}{(p+2)q!}$

$=\frac{(p+(q+1)+1)!}{(q+1)!}\left(\frac{n}{p+1}-\frac{q+1}{p+2}\right)$ (Proved)

Comment: How to know which variable to induce in these types of problems?

Comment: RHS contains 3 variables $p, q, n$ but does not contain $m$, the quantity that varies on LHS is the upper bound of the variable $m$ to be summed on, which is $q$. Hence, $q$ is the variable to induct on.