# A proof using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Use induction to prove that for any positive integers $m,s$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{s}\frac{n!}{(n+m)!} = \frac{1}{m-1} \left( \frac{1}{m!} - \frac{(s+1)!}{(s+m)!}\right)$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070606/how-do-i-solve-this-question-based-on-induction

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee I already fixed that problem. The trick is we fix $m$ and induct on $s$. Thank you.